# Combine scroll triggered and hover animation

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I am using a scroll triggered animation to fade in my card elements.Additionally I wanted to include a hover animation, but the animation changes back to the initial state after the hover, which is the state before the cards are faded in.

To trigger the scrolling animation I use this component here

```
export const useScroll = (treshhold = .2) => {
    const controls = useAnimation();
    const [element, view] = useInView({ threshold: treshhold, triggerOnce: true });
    if (view) {
        controls.start('show');
    } else {
        controls.start('hidden');
    }
    return [element, controls];
}
```

The element that is to be animated:

```
const [element, controls] = useScroll();
<StyledCard onClick={openCardHandler} style={style} layoutId={content.id} ref={element} variants={popup} initial="hidden" animate={controls} whileHover="hover">
```

And the animation looks like this:

```
export const popup = {
hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
    scale: .5
},
show: {
    opacity: 1,
    scale: 1,
    transition: {
        duration: .75
    }
},
hover: {
    scale: 1.2
}
}
```

Why does the animation state jump back to initial after the hover and not to show?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem. Removed the initial state property from the element and it works.